# ember.js registerBoundHelper: creating an if-like helper that performs server-side authorization via json

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ember.js, cancan, handlebars.js, ember-data

javascript/coffeescript/ember.js/stackoverflow newbie here!

I'm trying to create an if-like helper that will display content only when the action on an object is authorized from the server.  Basically I want the `can?` method from the rails cancan gem.  I want to write the template something like this:

```
<h1>Viewing profile for {{email}}</h1>
<h2>Scores</h2>
{{#each score in scores}}
    <div class="summary">{{score.what}}  
        {{#can score action=destroy}}
            <a href="#" id="destroy">Destroyable</a>  
        {{/can}}
        {{#can score action=view}}
            <a href="#" id="view">Viewable</a>  
        {{/can}}
        {{#can score action=edit}}
            <a href="#" id="edit">Editable</a>  
        {{/can}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

The `can` ember.js helper will query the server with a json request that looks something like this:

```
<site>/api/v1/authorization.json?action=destroy&cName=Score&id=1
```

The server would simply return the HTTP status codes 200 or 401, and ember would magically display or hide the content based on the status code.  I have to do the authorization this way because there's some role- & object based permissions checks that have to happen on the server, and I don't want to duplicate the authorization logic in js.

So far, I've used the out-of-the-box `if` helper as an example to create the following custom bound helper (coffeescript).

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper 'can', (object, options) ->

    permission = EmberDeviseExample.Authorization.create
        action: options.hash.action
        object: object

    permission.authorize()

    options.contexts = [permission]

    Ember.Handlebars.helpers.boundIf.call(permission, "can", options)
```

Here's the User object:

```
EmberDeviseExample.User = DS.Model.extend
  email:        DS.attr('string')
  scores:       DS.hasMany('EmberDeviseExample.Score')

EmberDeviseExample.store.adapter.serializer.map('EmberDeviseExample.User', {scores: {embedded: 'load'}})
```

And here's the Authorization object:

```
EmberDeviseExample.Authorization = Ember.Object.extend
  action: ''
  object: null
  response: 401
  urlBase: ApiUrl.authorization_path

  can : (-> 
      return (this.get('response') == 200)
  ).property('response')

  authorize: ->
    # if object is an instance, include the id in the query params
    # otherwise, just include the class name
    obj = this.get('object')
    cName = obj.toString()
    id = null
    if Ember.typeOf(obj) == "instance"
      # cname looks something like "<namespace.name:embernumber>"
      # turn it into "name"
      cName = cName.split(':')[0].split('.')[1]
      id = obj.get('id')

    $.ajax 
       url : "#{this.get('urlBase')}.json"
       context : this
       type : 'GET'
       data : 
          action : this.get('action')
          cName : cName
          id : id

       complete : (data, textStatus, xhr) ->
          this.set('response', data.status)

    return this.get('can')
```

On the server side, the authorization.json code looks like this (rails 3).  I am using the cancan gem to control authorization:

```
class AuthorizationsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  def show
    id     = params[:id]
    cName  = params[:cName]
    action = params[:action]

    object = cName.capitalize.constantize

    object = object.find(id) unless id.blank?

    authorized = can? action, object

    render status: (authorized ? 200 : 401), json: {}
  end
end
```

And the routes look like this:

```
  scope "/api" do
    scope "/v1" do
      resource :authorization, only: [:show]
    end
  end
```

Of course there's other code in my app, let me know if you need to see it.

When I remove the `#can` helpers, I see the rendered template.  When I add the `#can` helpers back in, I get a javascript error, the message in Chrome is `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null" @ ember.prod.js:2362.`

Does anyone know how to build a helper that accepts an object and action, runs a server-side authorization check, and displays/hides content based on the server result?

Comment: BTW, if there's a better way to do this content hiding, please post it!

Answer (score 0):

Just came accross your question, a bit late but probably I still can help.

Although it is complex to see where the error can come from, I see a problem in your intended implementation: you are binding the custom if helper to the property 'score', while the property observing the change in the response is called 'can', as the helper... (but this one is not observed from the helper nor they are bound anyhow!)

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but at this stage I honestly wouldn't know if this is the correct answer.  I think I found some workaround for this issue, then shortly after decided to give it up and wait for ember.js to mature.